# Ler arquivo csv utilizando como delimititador o caractere "|" - Python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Tentei  criar um DataFrame com a lib pandas de um arquivo que me é enviado no seguinte formato:

```
--------------------------------
|Indice|Preço|Quantidade|Cidade|
--------------------------------
|1|1000|2|São Paulo|
.
.
.
```

Utilizei o método read_csv com o delimitador "|" e recebo o seguinte erro:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe7 in position 3: invalid continuation byte
```

Tentei utilizar algumas outras codificações porém não consegui a maneira que me separasse os dados corretamente. Hoje em dia uso o excel para fazer essa divisão e excluir as linhas tracejadas (------).

Agradeço desde já a ajuda que puderem me dar.

Answer (score 2):

Acredito que o erro ocorra por causa do ã do São Paulo. Em campos de Texto, o valor deveria estar entre ". Mas você pode tentar também definir o encoding da função. Segue exemplo:

```
read_csv('arquivo.csv',encoding='iso-8859-1',delimiter ='|')
```

Documentação da função: 
http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html

Questão relacionada: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30462807/encoding-error-in-panda-read-csv

Obs: Se você abre no excel para remover as linhas tracejadas, imagino que seja uma operação manual e não uma rotina automática. Tente utilizar o notepad++ que pode alterar o texto em vários arquivos de uma vez, e substituir esses pipes por ponto-virgula. Há também a possibilidade de criar macros para editar o texto de forma automática.